# Avoidance Vs. Procrastination? Dorsolateral prefrontal cortex and the go-no-go task

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, lateralization, procrastination

The left dorsolateral prefrontal cortex (Ldlpfc) and the ventromedial prefrontal cortex (vmpfc) has been identified as having some positive functional correlation to procrastination.

From what I gather, this is because

- the left-lateral PFC tends to be implicated in "go" / "stay" tasks.
- The L-dlpfc is a target in brain stimulation for anxiety, to increase contentedness and decrease negative fixation (citations below)

Lets assume two things:

- definition: "procrastinating IS DOING something enjoyable at the expense of something more necessary in the longer term"
- definition: "avoidance is NOT DOING something which is necessary in the long term".

Clearly these two notions overlap: procrastination is avoidance (because procrastination = avoidance + preferred or distracting activity.

**QUESTIONS**: It seems like pure avoidance is more akin to "can't-go" and procrastination to the "can't-*not*-go".

1. *Is there any reason to think that increased right-lateralization  of brain activity (which may help the procrastinator) will not help the avoider?(since this “can’t-go” network is already hyper-active during avoidance and no-go task)*
2. *Thoughts and Reference would be greatly appreciated*

[Identifying the Neural Substrates of Procrastination(nih.gov)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5018960/)

[direct current stimulation over right dorsolateral prefrontal cortex alters decision making during approach-avoidance conflict (nih.gov)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5390716/)